# JSF and primefaces p:booleancheckbox not rendering correctly

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a strange behaviour in my code that for some reason I'm unable to solve.

I'm using PF4 and mojarra 2.1.28 running on jboss eap 6.4.

Here's the code

```
    <p:column>
    <f:facet name="header">                     
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkAll" value="#{backingBean.allowAll}">
            <p:ajax listener="#{backingBean.confirmAllowAlla}" process="tablaDoc" update="tablaDoc :form1:facesMessages" onstart="mask();" oncomplete="unmask();" />
        </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>                          
        <p:outputLabel for="checkAll" value="Allow all" />  
    </f:facet>
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkTipo" value="#{tipoDocumento.allowed}" >
        <f:param name="idTipoDocumento" value="#{tipoDocumento.idTipoDocumento}"/>
        <f:param name="secuencia" value="#{tipoDocumento.secuencia}"/>
        <p:ajax listener="#{backingBean.confirmChange(tipoDocumento)}" process="@this" update="tablaDoc :form1:facesMessages" onstart="mask();" oncomplete="unmask();" />
    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
</p:column>
```

Getters and setters exist, backing bean is invoked as it should... apparently everything works but...

when I click in the booleanCheckbox placed in the header all the other checkboxes should be checked.

First time I click internally everything seems to go ok. Model is updated correctly and my datatable is updated accordingly but for the checks. Visually they are not checked (checked="checked" is missing in the output html) but all the expected behaviour is just fine. A button for each row is enabled/disabled  and even if I add a column to display the internal value used for the check it renders the expected value.

If I uncheck the main checkbox and check it again, normal behaviour is restored and the checks for each row start rendering ok (checked="checked is in the output html).

I cannot modify my DTOs so I cannot implement SelectableDataModel from PrimeFaces.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, Several things: - I did not downvote yet, but please read http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ - And if needed you can always wrap a class. - And PF 4.0 is old...

Comment: It seems to me a container rendering issue... sometimes it is trickier to update a component from inside it which is your case... a possible workaround is to add a hidden button outside of your table and you call it upon the checkbox change event. and this button should update not the table but its container instead like `<p:outputPanel id="someParentContainer"> <inputButton update="someParentContainer"> <yourDataTable>...` **be aware** this is an ugly workaround but it usually works. You can also try to update the someParentContainer from your checkbox

Comment: And as @Kukeltje said PF 4 is OLD af... you should definitely get rid of it, problems will be even worst

Comment: Thanks @JorgeCampos. Tried your approach and the odd behaviour stays the same.  i'd use Pf6 if i could but that kind of choice is not up to me :)

Comment: And there doesn't do `backingBean.allowAll` and `backingBean.confirmAllowAlla` do the same job? `backingBean.allowAll` will be sent already changed to your bean. So `backingBean.confirmAllowAlla` should not change the allowAll-value, too.

Comment: confirm shows a dialog to accept or cancel if data was added in each row before deleting it. if you click on cancel model values are reverted to previous state and if you confirm you procceed as if no data is present in that row. it's a weird behaviour. i've added some javascript to force the change of the value in the checkboxes and now it does update as it should, but i'm totally convinced that it has something to do with using old versions of PF and jsf.